# Is it possible to make a recusive method in java that doesn't return before your criteria is met?

Tags: java, recursion

This is what I've tried:

```
private static ApplicationGroup fetchDashboardParamInfo(List<ApplicationGroup> applicationGroup, String uniqueId) {
    ApplicationGroup dashParamInfo = null;
    for (ApplicationGroup a : applicationGroup) {
        if (a.getUniqueId() == null || !a.getUniqueId().equals(uniqueId)) {
            fetchDashboardParamInfo(a.getChildren(), uniqueId);
        } else if (a.getUniqueId().equals(uniqueId)) {
            dashParamInfo = a;
        }
    }
    return dashParamInfo;
}
```

I'm simply running throug applicationGroup which is a list of application groups. It's actually a hierarchy of application groups. I'm trying to make the method recurse if the "if"-statement is true, with a.getChildren() as the new a. If the "else if"-statement is true, dashParamInfo should simply be equal to whatever a is at that point, and then the method should return dashParamInfo without further looping. The problem I have is that when the "if"-statement becomes true, it doesn't recurse, it goes inside the statement but then it just goes to return and ends the method right away. What am I doin wrong?

Comment: What are you returning after calling fetchDashboardParamInfo inside if/else. I think the return should be captured like dashParamInfo = fetchDashboardParamInfo

Comment: @prashant this does give the correct result but it's not quite recursive. It does not run the method again if the first if statement is true.. The reason why it gives the correct method is because of the way I've built the hierarchy. But it is not the ideal way to do it, i need it to recurse.

Comment: You haven't assigned the value found by your inner function "fetchDashboardParamInfo".  You need to assign it to a variable, then decide what to do with that result.

Comment: @Arvind Kumar Avinash - Nope, still looking for a solution. None of the answers work.

Answer (score 1):

If the correct answer is not found in the current `applicationGroup` you need to recurse deeper. But if you recurse you need to check if the recurrent call has found what you were looking for; if so, you need to return it.

```
private static ApplicationGroup fetchDashboardParamInfo(List<ApplicationGroup> applicationGroup, String uniqueId) {
    for (ApplicationGroup a : applicationGroup) {
        if (a.getUniqueId() == null || !a.getUniqueId().equals(uniqueId)) {
            ApplicationGroup dashParamInfo = fetchDashboardParamInfo(a.getChildren(), uniqueId);
            if (dashParamInfo != null)
                return dashParamInfo;
        } else if (a.getUniqueId().equals(uniqueId)) {
            return a;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing             `return` before `fetchDashboardParamInfo(a.getChildren(), uniqueId);`

```
private static ApplicationGroup fetchDashboardParamInfo(List<ApplicationGroup> applicationGroup, String uniqueId) {
    ApplicationGroup dashParamInfo = null;
    for (ApplicationGroup a : applicationGroup) {
        if (a.getUniqueId() == null || !a.getUniqueId().equals(uniqueId)) {
            return fetchDashboardParamInfo(a.getChildren(), uniqueId);
        } else if (a.getUniqueId().equals(uniqueId)) {
            dashParamInfo = a;
            break;
        }
    }
    return dashParamInfo;
}
```

Comment: This is does not work, because if the first if statement is true then it quits the method. This is not what I'm looking for. I'm looking for it to recurse if the first if statement is true and then quit if the second one is true.